# JSON file schema evaluation using json-schema-validator

Tags: java, json, json-schema-validator

I have a sample JSON file and I have also come up with a schema to evaluate above file using below JSON file:

```
//[gcp_ingestion_parameters_schema.json]
{
...
    "properties": {
        "application": {
            "$ref": "#/definitions/application"
        },
        "ingestion": {
            "$ref": "#/definitions/ingestion"
        }
    },
    "definitions": {
        "applicaion": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "project_id": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "path_to_json_key_file": {
                    "type": "string"
                }
            },
            "required": [
                "project_id",
                "path_to_json_key_file"
            ]
    },
 ...
```

I am still not sure how to write the schema file. In my sample file both application and ingestion tags should occur once, but fileingestion-mappings inside ingestion can occur one or more than once.

I have written some java code to evaluate my JSON file (first file) based on the provided JSON schema file.

but I get exception as follow:
Exception in thread "main"

```
com.github.fge.jsonschema.core.exceptions.ProcessingException: fatal: JSON Reference "#/definitions/appl
ication" cannot be resolved
    level: "fatal"
    schema: {"loadingURI":"#","pointer":"/properties/application"}
    ref: "#/definitions/application"
```

Can some with experience working wit above library answer my questions asked in this tread?

Answer (score 1):

As suggested you have a typo in ur schema it should be below

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
    "$id": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
    "title": "Core schema meta-schema",
    "definitions": {
        "schemaArray": {
            "type": "array",
            "minItems": 1,
            "items": { "$ref": "#" }
        },
        "nonNegativeInteger": {
            "type": "integer",
            "minimum": 0
        },
        "nonNegativeIntegerDefault0": {
            "allOf": [
                { "$ref": "#/definitions/nonNegativeInteger" },
                { "default": 0 }
            ]
        },
        "simpleTypes": {
            "enum": [
                "array",
                "boolean",
                "integer",
                "null",
                "number",
                "object",
                "string"
            ]
        },
        "stringArray": {
            "type": "array",
            "items": { "type": "string" },
            "uniqueItems": true,
            "default": []
        }
    },
    "type": ["object", "boolean"],
    "properties": {
        "$id": {
            "type": "string",
            "format": "uri-reference"
        },
        "$schema": {
            "type": "string",
            "format": "uri"
        },
        "$ref": {
            "type": "string",
            "format": "uri-reference"
        },
        "$comment": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "title": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "description": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "default": true,
        "readOnly": {
            "type": "boolean",
            "default": false
        },
        "examples": {
            "type": "array",
            "items": true
        },
        "multipleOf": {
            "type": "number",
            "exclusiveMinimum": 0
        },
        "maximum": {
            "type": "number"
        },
        "exclusiveMaximum": {
            "type": "number"
        },
        "minimum": {
            "type": "number"
        },
        "exclusiveMinimum": {
            "type": "number"
        },
        "maxLength": { "$ref": "#/definitions/nonNegativeInteger" },
        "minLength": { "$ref": "#/definitions/nonNegativeIntegerDefault0" },
        "pattern": {
            "type": "string",
            "format": "regex"
        },
        "additionalItems": { "$ref": "#" },
        "items": {
            "anyOf": [
                { "$ref": "#" },
                { "$ref": "#/definitions/schemaArray" }
            ],
            "default": true
        },
        "maxItems": { "$ref": "#/definitions/nonNegativeInteger" },
        "minItems": { "$ref": "#/definitions/nonNegativeIntegerDefault0" },
        "uniqueItems": {
            "type": "boolean",
            "default": false
        },
        "contains": { "$ref": "#" },
        "maxProperties": { "$ref": "#/definitions/nonNegativeInteger" },
        "minProperties": { "$ref": "#/definitions/nonNegativeIntegerDefault0" },
        "required": { "$ref": "#/definitions/stringArray" },
        "additionalProperties": { "$ref": "#" },
        "definitions": {
            "type": "object",
            "additionalProperties": { "$ref": "#" },
            "default": {}
        },
        "properties": {
            "type": "object",
            "additionalProperties": { "$ref": "#" },
            "default": {}
        },
        "patternProperties": {
            "type": "object",
            "additionalProperties": { "$ref": "#" },
            "propertyNames": { "format": "regex" },
            "default": {}
        },
        "dependencies": {
            "type": "object",
            "additionalProperties": {
                "anyOf": [
                    { "$ref": "#" },
                    { "$ref": "#/definitions/stringArray" }
                ]
            }
        },
        "propertyNames": { "$ref": "#" },
        "const": true,
        "enum": {
            "type": "array",
            "items": true,
            "minItems": 1,
            "uniqueItems": true
        },
        "type": {
            "anyOf": [
                { "$ref": "#/definitions/simpleTypes" },
                {
                    "type": "array",
                    "items": { "$ref": "#/definitions/simpleTypes" },
                    "minItems": 1,
                    "uniqueItems": true
                }
            ]
        },
        "format": { "type": "string" },
        "contentMediaType": { "type": "string" },
        "contentEncoding": { "type": "string" },
        "if": {"$ref": "#"},
        "then": {"$ref": "#"},
        "else": {"$ref": "#"},
        "allOf": { "$ref": "#/definitions/schemaArray" },
        "anyOf": { "$ref": "#/definitions/schemaArray" },
        "oneOf": { "$ref": "#/definitions/schemaArray" },
        "not": { "$ref": "#" }
    },
    "default": true
}
```

This works perfectly fine with the JSON you have provided.

Answer (score 0):

You have typo error in `applicaion` it should be `application`

Change this `"definitions": { "applicaion": {` to `"definitions": { "application": {`

also Refer this link to validate your schema https://www.liquid-technologies.com/online-json-schema-validator.